# Contact form sending emails from and to the same email -Django

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms

So I am building a three-section webpage and one of these sections contains a contact form for users to send messages to my email (`EMAIL_HOST_USER` in `settings.py`). But `send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [email_to,], fail_silently=False)` is only using `EMAIL_HOST_USER` for both the sender and the recipient parts and it sends the email from and to that email. And I can't figure out what I am missing here.

Here's the code and thank you in advance.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from hajar.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import ContactForm 

def base_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Hello"
            name   = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email_from =  form.cleaned_data['email']   
            email_to = EMAIL_HOST_USER   
            message= form.cleaned_data['message']
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [email_to,], fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponse(f'Thank you for your message, {name}!')
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name    = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input required', 'id':'name'}))
    email   = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'mdl-textfield__input required', 'id':'email'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'mdl-textfield__input required', 'id':'textarea'}))
```

Comment: You are sending to the email host user. `email_to = EMAIL_HOST_USER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `EmailMessage` class for sending replies to other emails.

```
email = EmailMessage(
    subject=subject,
    body=message,
    from_email=email_from,
    to=[email_to],
    reply_to=[email_from],
)

email.send()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to let people send me emails through the contact form. And I think setting email_to = form.cleaned_data['email'] would work as a subscription list because I'd be the one who is sending the emails.

Comment: @Hajar It is not possible what you are trying to do. You are using SMTP credentials of **your**  email account on your server, how someone else's email account/address can be used as the sender? What you can do is, set `reply_to` header in your email so that replies are sent to true recipients when done. For that, you should use EmailMessage class. Please se updated answer.

Comment: OH WOW! It's working now. I knew I was doing something stupid but didn't know about the EmailMessage class, none of the tutorials I've seen so far has mentioned it. Thank you SO much, really.