# Fetching data from template to send email

Tags: html, django, email

please this is the html file i am trying to fetch the data to be able to send it to my settings email

```
<form action="{% url 'send'%}" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
              </form>
```

and this is my views.py which i collected the data from the html file

```
def sendEmail(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        subject = request.POST['subject']
        message = request.POST['message']

        send_mail(
            "Contact Form",
            message,
            email,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            fail_silently=False
        )
    return render(request, 'app/index.html')
```

and my settings for the email which i am using gmail

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and my urls.py is which i sent it to my url to the views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('sendmail/', views.sendEmail, name='send'),

]
```

Comment: And the question is???

Comment: what does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: please i want to be able to send the form to my settings email

Comment: Hey Joseph. Please see the console for any error. Also did you enable the google less secure apps for local development? https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: It's not good for production purposes. You may look into SendGrid or other sending email providers.

Comment: okay thanks  i will look at it

Comment: Hey, so here's a link to a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802624/contact-form-sending-emails-from-and-to-the-same-email-django/59802690#59802690. Hope it helps.